# Consumo de API com múltiplas requisições

Tags: api, rest

Bom dia!

Preciso fazer varias requisições em uma API REST, utilizando PHP, passando múltiplos parâmetros. atualmente faço um `foreach` utilizando uma variável na url.

Porem devido ao tempo de processamento e retornado o erro **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in**.

Já tentei aumentar `max_execution_time`, `max_input_time` e *`memory_limit`*, funcionou por um tempo, porem quando as requisições aumentam e preciso aumentar os valores dos parâmetros novamente, tornando pouco viável.

Gostaria de saber se ha possibilidades de fazer de uma forma mais eficiente, atualmente faço da seguinte forma:

*EX: Tenho uma lista de CEPs e preciso consultar a API para saber Logradouro referente a eles e retornar em uma lista.*

```
foreach($registros -> result() as $consulta):
  $url = "https://webmaniabr.com/api/1/cep/{$consulta->cep}";
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $result = json_decode($json);
endforeach;
```

Comment: Na documentação da API diz: "A WebmaniaBR® aplica um limite de até 10 solicitações por segundo e 5.000 solicitações por dia na API..." será que não é melhor utilizar outra API?

Comment: Utilizei essa API somente como exemplo, para ficar mais fácil o entendimento, a que eu uso realmente no projeto e uma de consulta a tabela FIPE, que não tem limite de requisição.
A limitação fica por conta do tempo de execução mesmo, como eu disse, quando aumento o max_execution_time ele funciona, mas ai tenho que colocar um valor muito alto, e quando atinge novamente tenho que aumentar de novo

Comment: Entendi... mas, não tem como vc enviar um jSON com um array de requisições de uma vez ao invés de fazer um foreach? Acho que esse deve ser o caminho!

Comment: Já experimentou utilizar o **curl_multi_exec**? São quantas requisições atualmente? A depender do que você queira fazer, nem vale a pena usar PHP.